# Create Array From List of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hi First time Post here , please do forgive my poor English.

I have a list of data as follow

```
var list = '1,2,3,4,8,9,10,20,21,22,23,24'
```

i would like to convert this list to array, something like this

```
var array = ([1,4],[8,10],[20,24]);
```

Which it will take the first and the **last(1-4)** element of the list before it jump to another **variable(8-10)**.

I have come out with some code but it's very messy

```
var first = true;
var firstvalue = '';
var b ='';
var endvalue ='';
var last = '';
var myArray = [];
$('.highlight').each(function() {//Loop in list
    if(first){//Only For the first time to set up the loop
        firstvalue = this.id;
        b = firstvalue;
        first = false;
        return;
    }

    if(parseInt(this.id)-1 != b){//When gap happen and new array is insert
        endvalue = b;

        /*save here*/
        myArray.push([firstvalue,endvalue]);

        firstvalue = this.id;
        b = firstvalue;
    }else{
        b = this.id;

    }

        last = this.id;//Last Item that cant capture
    });
    myArray.push([firstvalue,last]);
```

Are there any better way for this ?

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail how you're selecting the values to be put in the array from your list. How do you go from `[1,4]` to `[8,10]`. Also your code has a syntax error due to an extra closing bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: easy and simple method.

```js
    var list = '1,2,3,4,8,9,10,20,21,22,23,24';
    list = list.split(',');
    var arrayList = [];
    var firstEle = 0, lastEle = 0;
    list[-1] = -2;

    for(var i=-1; i<list.length; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            firstEle = list[0];

        if(((list[i+1] - list[i]) > 1) && i >= 0 && i <= (list.length - 1))
        {
            lastEle = list[i];
            arrayList.push('['+firstEle+','+lastEle+']');
            firstEle = list[i+1];
        }
        else if(i == (list.length - 1))
        {
            lastEle = list[i];
            arrayList.push('['+firstEle+','+lastEle+']');
        }
    }
    alert(arrayList);
```

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, Kindly accept it. It will be helpful for other users.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
var result=[];
var list = '1,2,3,4,8,9,10,20,21,22,23,24'
var dataOflist=list.split(',');

var l=dataOflist.splice(dataOflist.length-4,4);
var f=dataOflist.splice(0,4);
result[0]=f;
result[1]=dataOflist;
result[2]=l;
console.log(result);
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and convert all values to number. Then use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with the generated array and check the predecessor and the actual value.

If unequal with the incremented predeccessor, then concat a new array with the actual value to the result set.

Otherwise update the value at index `1` of the last array in the result set.

It works for any range sizes.

```js
var list = '1,2,3,4,8,9,10,20,21,22,23,24',
    result = list.split(',').map(Number).reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        if (aa[i - 1] + 1 !== a) {
            return r.concat([[a]]);
        }
        r[r.length - 1][1] = a;
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```js
var list = '1,2,3,4,8,9,10,20,21,22,23,24,26,27,28,30';

list = list.split(',').map(x => parseInt(x));
list.push(Infinity);
console.log(JSON.stringify(list));

var startIndex = 0;
var result = list.reduce((a, b, i, arr) => {

  if(i != 0 && b - 1 != arr[i-1])
  {
    a.push([arr[startIndex], arr[i-1]]);
    startIndex = i;
  }
  return a;
  
}, []);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```